# How to tell which ajax request failed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this code block to post a HTTP request via jquery .post() method.

```
$.post("/product/update", formPostData)
.done(function (data) {
    // success
    alert(data.product_id + ' was updated!');
})
.fail(function (data) {
    // fail, but which request?
});
```

When it is successful it is easy to know which request we are dealing with, since the json returned by the server has the `'product_id'` that I need.

But if it fails due to an error in which the server is not responsive, a connectivity problem for example, how can I tell which request has failed?

The `data` object has no clues because it only contains the server response.

How can I pass a value to the `.fail()` handler so I can determine which request has failed?

Comment: Do you mean that you are calling this multiple times with different values for `formPostData` and you don't know which call has failed?

Comment: What do you mean "which request failed"? You are only showing code for one request. If you hit the `.fail()` function, you know that it is the `post` that `fail` is connected to that failed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `this` object is useful here. You should be able to parse `this.data` and get your post information from there:

```
.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log(this.data);
});
```

Comment: `this.url` will contain the url of the request.

Comment: @JoeEnos `formPostData` is the posted data. That would be accessible in the `fail`.

Comment: @JoeEnos that works. But is there not a better way that does not involve parsing the query string?

Comment: Had to delete my other comments after realizing my local example was different...Yes, you can access that `postData` object in the `fail` function, assuming you've stored it in a variable, and aren't doing anything weird like calling this in a loop while reassigning the variable to a different value. If you're posting JSON rather than form-encoded, then the `this.data` text will be easy to parse. Otherwise, there are libraries to parse url-encoded values.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative would be write to the XHR object itself, and then it's there for you in the `fail` method, and wouldn't require you to use a closure:

```
var obj = { a: 1 };
var xhr = $.post("/product/update", obj)
   .done(function (data) {})
   .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(this.data); // The raw string a=1 which was posted
        console.log(jqXHR.postData); // The {a: 1} javascript object
   });
xhr.postData = obj;
```

Comment: This is very helpful. Thank you very much.